# LeafletJS: Is it possible to show an ImageOverlay over a VectorLayer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

When I call "img_overlay_layer.bringToFront()" method it only brings it to the top of overlay images layers. 
Is there any possibility of making an image overlay appear on top of vector layers?

I need the ability to show a pile like this (top to bottom):

- Image Overlay
- Vector Layer
- Image Overlay
- Vector Layer
- Tile Layer

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Leaflet's [map panes](https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/) feature in order to achieve precise separation and z-index ordering of your layers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've checked the link in a glance and it seems to be exactly what I am looking for. Tomorrow I will try it and confirm your answer if it works as expected (I bet that it will).